# Code to simulate race condition in Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java multithreading.  I am learning the concept of race condition.

Based on the Oracle document

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html

I created a sample code like the one below

```
public class CounterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new CounterIncThread());
        thread1.setName("add thread");
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new CounterDecThread());
        thread2.setName("sub thread");
        thread2.start();

        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new CounterIncThread());
        thread3.setName("add thread2");
        thread3.start();
    }

}


class CounterIncThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        SynchronizedCounter counter = new SynchronizedCounter();
        counter.increment();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String threadName =
                Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(threadName+ ": "+counter.value());
    }
}

class CounterDecThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        SynchronizedCounter counter = new SynchronizedCounter();
        counter.decrement();
        String threadName =
                Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(threadName+ ": "+counter.value());
    }
}

class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int c = 0;

    public  void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public   void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public  int value() {
        return c;
    }

}
```

The code doesn't show any racing condition.  Can you please help me, how to stimulate the race condition using the above code?

Thanks

Comment: stimulate or simulate :D?

Comment: sorry its simulate :D

Comment: Well all those counter classes are not shared between threads. They are local to your run method! You cannot get into a race condition that way! ;)

Comment: Oh!  Do I need to update CounterIncThread and CounterDecThread classes?

Comment: @Icewind  - He is also *not* sharing the *same runnable* object between threads.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to have a race between two threads, there must be shared state between those two threads and interaction (reading and writing) to that state must occur outside of a mutualy exclusive block (aka syncronized).  Reading, incrementing and then writing back to a volatile field outside of a synchronized block is a great example of this.

For example, consider this situation documented on this [blog](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/race-condition-synchronization-atomic.html).

Both thread A and B could read the counter before any modification occurs.  They then both increment, and they then both write.  The end result will then be 18, and not 19.  For it to have been 19, we would have needed thread B to read the counter AFTER thread A had written to the counter.  Which, can happen sometimes.  That is why it is called a race.

[image]

To reliably achieve this kind of race, change your test code above to create the counter outside of the threads and then pass it in to them via their constructors.

The second problem that you have is that the window for the operations to overlap is very fine, and given that starting a thread has, in comparison  a lot of over head then the chances of these three threads over lapping at just the right time is very low.   Thus to increase their odds, you should repeat the runs in a tight loop.

The following code demonstrates the two concepts above.  The changes made have been:

1. renamed classes to make their use a little clearer
2. shared the state of MyCounter between the two threads
3. tight loop within each thread, calling increment 1,000,000 times
4. the main thread now blocks using join() waiting for the two threads to complete, this replaces the Thread.sleep that you had earlier
5. the counter value c in MyCounter is now volatile;  this tells the JVM to always go out to shared memory for the value and not to optimise by keeping it within a register between encounters.  to make the race much worse, take volatile off and see what happens :)
6. the main loop then finishes by printing out the value of the counter, which should be 2,000,000.  but it will not be due to the race that is going on over the volatile counter.

.

```
public class CounterTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {   
        MyCounter counter = new MyCounter();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new CounterIncRunnable(counter));
        thread1.setName("add thread");
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new CounterIncRunnable(counter));
        thread2.setName("add thread2");
        thread2.start();

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();

        System.out.println(counter.value());
    }    
}


class CounterIncRunnable implements Runnable {
    private MyCounter counter;

    public CounterIncRunnable(MyCounter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void run() {
        for ( int i=0; i<1000000; i++ ) {
            counter.increment();
        }
    }
}


class MyCounter {
    private volatile int c = 0;

    public  void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public   void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public  int value() {
        return c;
    }    
}
```

Finally, just for fun;  add synchronized to the increment method of MyCounter and then rerun.  The race condition will disappear, and now the program will correctly print 2000000.  This is because every call to increment will now only allow one thread in to the shared method at a time.  Thus serializing each access to the shared variable c, and putting an end to the race.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest kind of race condition is where two threads are updating some shared data using this pattern

```
  read a value
  think for a bit, giving another thread a chance to get in
  increment the value and write it back
```

So now if you have two threads running, each incrementing a counter whose initial value is 43, we expect this

```
  A reads value 43
  A thinks
  A increments and writes 44
  B reads value 44
  B thinks
  B increments and writes 45
```

but this could happen, because of the "think window"

```
  A reads value 43
  A thinks
  B reads value (it's still) 43
  B thinks
  B increments 43 to 44 and writes
  A increments 43 to 44 and write
  // the value is now 44, and we expected it to be 45
```

The key idea for a race is that you get unexpectedly bad effects, for example in an inventory application, two threads each decrement the amount of stock, and just like in the example above we "lose" one of the decrements.

Now your code has two issues:

1). no shared values so we have no chance to see any such contention

2). You're incrementing an integer in a single line of code, so there's very little chance of two threads clashing. In simulating a race it's better to separate the read and write as I show above, and then create a "window of opportunity" by sleeping to simulate thinking time. In multi-processor environment where threads may truly be running in parallel even a single line of code could conceivably get a race because the JVM will internally be doing reads and writes and may even keep a cache of the values.

Answer (score 2):

You are operating on a different object in each thread, thus there is no race condition.So first you need to share the `SynchronizedCounter` (btw this is a confusing name). Add a `counter` member in each runnable.

```
CounterIncThread(SynchronizedCounter counter)
{
   this->counter = counter;
}

CounterDecThread(SynchronizedCounter counter)
{
   this->counter = counter;
}

...
SynchronizedCounter counter = new SynchronizedCounter();
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new CounterIncThread(counter));
Thread thread2 = new Thread(new CounterDecThread(counter));
Thread thread3 = new Thread(new CounterIncThread(counter));
```

Also. You are doing only one operation in the runnable. This may not be enough to display the race condition. So loop over a great amount of time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) <-- 100000 is just on the top of my head
{
    counter.increment(); 
}
```

The value will not be the sum of the operation if the race occured,in my case I expect it to be `100000 * 2`.

To be even more explicit, run several time. You will likely obtain different values

Answer (score 0):

If the prints are shown "correctly", is because there are not much threads. Try to create 100 threads and you will see that prints are not shown sorted. If `c` in SynchronizedCounter is static, you can see race condition, since the threads are reading the same variable.